# Sort Array by occurrence of its elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for an elegant way of sorting an array by the occurrence of its elements.

For example, in:

```
['pear', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple']
```

the output should look like

```
['apple', 'orange', 'pear']
```

I have tried to loop through the array and save the occurrence in another temporary array, but this solution was quite bad.

Comment: You have to loop through . without looping in you can't

Comment: Why was your solution bad? Can you post it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would require two loops.

```js
    var arr = ['pear', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple'];
    //find the counts using reduce
    var cnts = arr.reduce( function (obj, val) {
        obj[val] = (obj[val] || 0) + 1;
        return obj;
    }, {} );
    //Use the keys of the object to get all the values of the array
    //and sort those keys by their counts
    var sorted = Object.keys(cnts).sort( function(a,b) {
        return cnts[b] - cnts[a];
    });
    console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Something tells me that it looks like "two loops" but takes more internally (for eg `Object.keys`). Am I wrong..?

Comment: Yes technically it is looping internally. If that is a big performance hit, it is as simple as pushing to an array inside of reduce when the key is not there.

Comment: No I'm not saying it's a performance hit or anything, I was just curious that there might be some hidden magic  (*done for  performance optimization*) internally

Answer (score 2):

Map the values into a fruit→count associated object:

```
var counted = fruits.reduce(function (acc, fruit) {
    if (acc[fruit]) {
        acc[fruit]++;
    } else {
        acc[fruit] = 1;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Map that object into a sortable array:

```
var assoc = counted.keys().map(function (fruit) {
    return [fruit, counted[fruit]];
});
```

Sort the array:

```
assoc.sort(function (a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; });
```

Extract the values:

```
var result = assoc.map(function (i) { return i[0]; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var arr = ['pear', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple'];
var result = [];
var count = 0;

arr.sort();

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  count++;
  if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
    result.push({
      "count": count,
      "value": arr[i]
    });
    count = 0;
  }
}

result.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.count < b.count) return 1;
  if (a.count > b.count) return -1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(result.map(function(item){return item.value}));
```

Comment: @TJ, can you explain the issue? Output in console is a sorted array of unique elements

Comment: The question is to sort *by number of occurrences!*

Comment: @deceze have updated my answer. Again apologies for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your array to remove duplicates and then sort with custom comparator:

```
var sorted = ['pear', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple'].reduce(function(result, item) {
    result.every(function(i) {
        return i != item;
    }) && result.push(item);
    return result;
}, []).sort(function(i1, i2) {
    return i1 > i2;
});
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) it is pretty easy (with [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yXNp5fAUVdVLdgobB8aC?p=preview)):

```
var array = ['pear', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple'];            
var res = Enumerable.From(array).GroupBy(function (x) { return x; }).Select(function (x) { return { key: x.Key(), count: x.Count() } }).OrderByDescending(function (x) { return x.count }).Select(function (x) { return x.key}).ToArray();
```

Comment: Clear solution in .Net LINQ style for those who well know it.

Comment: I don't think there's need to know linq to understand each of those function call at least runs a loop...

Answer (score 0):

You could try out [lodash](https://lodash.com/). All you need to do is `group`, `sort`, then `map` and you are done.

```js
var arr = ['pear', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple'];

document.body.innerHTML = _(arr).chain().groupBy()
  .sortBy(function(a) {
    return -a.length;   // <- Note: Remove the negation to sort in ascending order.
  }).map(function(a) {
    return a[0];
  }).value().join(', ');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/master/dist/lodash.js"></script>
```