# count of elements in array of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, count

I'm having array in Jquery like following,

```
[125, "321", "kar", 125, "sho", "sho", 12, 125, "32", 32]
```

It's having duplicate. I want count of each and every element in array(associative array).

Comment: Tried anything yourself?

Comment: No, no idea with this.

Comment: Try getting the unique values from the array first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array, then use `.length` of the new array.

Comment: Check following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396767/sort-array-by-occurrence-of-its-elements/34396876#34396876

Comment: `array in Jquery` - correction, that's a plain ol' javascript array - there's no such animal as a jquery array

Comment: You aren't manipulating the dom so you don't need jQuery, yes there are neat little functions like each that cut a few lines out of using an actual for loop but really it's overkill. You don't have an associative array, you have an array. Check out the docs at the mozilla developer network for javascript they are really useful for learning how to use javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Try following Script

```
var Items = [125, "321", "kar", 125, "sho", "sho", 12, 125, "32", 32],
    counts = {};

jQuery.each(Items , function(key,value) {
  if (!counts.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
    counts[value] = 1;
  } else {
    counts[value]++;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Populate a 'frequencies' object using values from the arry

```js
var frequencies = {};
[125, "321", "kar", 125, "sho", "sho", 12, 125, "32", 32].map( 
  function (v) {
    if (frequencies[v]) { frequencies[v] += 1; }
    else { frequencies[v] = 1; }
    return v;
}, frequencies);

var result = document.querySelector('#result');
result.textContent = JSON.stringify(frequencies, 0, 2) +
                     '\nAnd unique \'values\' from the frequencies object:\n[' +
                     Object.keys(frequencies).join(', ') + ']';
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

A very short version with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var array = [125, "321", "kar", 125, "sho", "sho", 12, 125, "32", 32],
    count = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a] = (r[a] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    }, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(count, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: even shorter: `return (r[a] =  (r[a] || 0) + 1) && r;` ;)

Comment: @KooiInc, too much parenthesis.

Comment: i know, the assignment needs the parenthesis. but it makes the code not more readable, as it is.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will give you a count of every element (whatever it is), except it will not differentiate between `+0` and `-0` (SameValueZero).

```js
var array = [125, "321", "kar", 125, "sho", "sho", 12, 125, "32", 32];
var counts = array.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  if (acc.has(item)) {
    acc.set(item, acc.get(item) + 1);
  } else {
    acc.set(item, 1);
  }
  return acc;
}, new Map());
document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(Array.from(counts), null, 2);
console.log(counts);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.0/es6-shim.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

And if you want an array of the unique values.

```js
var array = [125, "321", "kar", 125, "sho", "sho", 12, 125, "32", 32];
var unique = Array.from(new Set(array));
document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(unique, null, 2);
console.log(unique);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.0/es6-shim.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```